# ¿Como eliminar una fila de cliente con ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

No salta el mensaje ¿Está seguro de eliminar?, puede que sea por la url, .
HTML button

```html
<button data-id="<?= $row['id_cliente']?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Ajax trae información de un listado ajax

```js
(".listUsuarios").on("click", ".btn-danger", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var delete_usuario = confirm("¿Está seguro de eliminar?");
    if ( delete_usuario ) {
        var usuario_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: "admin.php?view=users&id_cliente="+usuario_id
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            if (data.resultado) {
                listUsuarios();
            }
            alert(data.mensaje);
        });
    }
});
```

PHP

```php
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id_user=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('id');
    if(MysqlQuery::Eliminar("cliente", "id_cliente='$id_user'")
```

Comment: Tu código Javascript escucha los clicks de los elementos que tienen la clase `listUsuarios`, pero el elemento HTML que compartes no tiene esa clase. Quizá lo que quisiste poner fue esto: `(".btn-danger").on("click", function(event) {` ¿?

Answer (score 2):

Tu código Javascript escucha los clicks de los elementos que tienen la clase `listUsuarios`, pero el elemento HTML que compartes no tiene esa clase (ten en cuenta que el punto es el selector de clase). Quizá lo que quisiste poner fue esto: `(".btn-danger").on("click", function(event) {`.

Aparte de eso, te falta poner el `$`, que es el indicador para elementos jQuery.

Así funciona:

```js
$(".btn-danger").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var delete_usuario = confirm("¿Está seguro de eliminar?");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id="<?= $row['id_cliente']?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Borrar</button>
```

Y, si quieres que escuche a dos o más clases, tienes que ponerlas separadas por comas en la parte del selector.

Observa que el listener funciona para ambos botones:

```js
$(".listUsuarios,.btn-danger").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var delete_usuario = confirm("¿Está seguro de eliminar?");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Clase btn-danger</button>

<hr />

<button class="listUsuarios"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Clase listUsuarios</button>
```

Para más detalles consulta [la documentación sobre el selector de clases en jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

---

En cuanto a la petición Ajax y el manejo de los datos en el servidor, no estás evaluando bien.

Primeramente, indicaste en la petición Ajax que el método era `get`, por tanto, debes ser coherente en el servidor y usar `$_GET`, no `$_POST`, aunque ese uso intercambiado funciona en algunos contextos hay que evitarlo.

Luego, tampoco estás buscando bien el índice en la super global.

Cuando envías algo así, en una URL:

```
url: "admin.php?view=users&id_cliente="+usuario_id
```

Lo que ocurre es que se crea un array (sí, `$_GET` y `$_POST` son arrays).

En este caso es como si declarases:

```
$_GET=array
            (
              'view'=>'user',
              'id_cliente'=>'elValorQueTenga usuario_id'
            );
```

Significa que esto nunca encontrará nada:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id_user=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('id');
    if(MysqlQuery::Eliminar("cliente", "id_cliente='$id_user'")
```

En el array que es `$_POST`  (o `$_GET`), no hay una clave `id`, en la URL tú pasaste una clave `id_cliente` asociada al valor de la variable. Además, usas una variable `$id_user` que no existe, al menos en ese contexto. Supongo que ese es el dato que viaja en `$_GET['id_cliente']`. Por tanto, ese bloque debería quedar así:

```
if(isset($_GET['id_cliente'])) {
    $id_user=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('id');
    if(MysqlQuery::Eliminar("cliente", "id_cliente='$_GET[id_cliente]'")
```

O, más elegante, para mi gusto:

```
#Verificamos el GET y guardamos una referencia
$id_cliente=!empty($_GET['id_cliente']) ? $_GET['id_cliente'] : NULL;

#En lo adelante usamos la variable en todo
if($id_cliente) {
    $id_user=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('id');
    if(MysqlQuery::Eliminar("cliente", "id_cliente=$id_cliente")
```

Comment: Si se me olvido poner aqui el $ gracias, salta el aviso, pero al aceptar sale un undefined y no lo borra, imagino que el problema es `$.ajax({
      method: "post",
      url: "admin.php?view=users&id_cliente="+usuario_id
    })`la url intento llamar a la misma pagina

Comment: @RaulRipolles revisa la respuesta editada. He puesto varias cosas al final sobre el manejo de los datos en PHP.